# Adding an attribute to all my models

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to separate my models in different blocks in my admin's index (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13957711/326849)).

In order to achieve that, I'd like to add an attribute "admin_group" to all my models. Then I'll override `AdminSite.app_index` and create a custom `admin/app_index.html` to group models by "admin_group" and show them in different blocks in my admin's index.

I can just add an attribute "admin_group" to my models, as shown below:

```
class model1(models.Model):
    # ...
    admin_group = "group1"

class model2(models.Model):
    # ...
    admin_group = "group1"

class model3(models.Model):
    # ...
    admin_group = "group2"
```

but I'm wondering whether there's a cleaner solution.

Note: I don't want to use the Meta option `app_label`, because it messes up the database requests.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505006/customize-django-admin-index-page-to-display-model-objects  you can add this property in meta.

Comment: is the "group1", "group2" needed or can you leave that value empty?

Comment: @danihp: I'd prefer to not modify django core.

Comment: @Rickard Zachrisson: that would be needed, because each model must belong to an admin_group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a Parent class with that group field and inherit all your model classes with Parent class.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    GROUP_CHOICES = [
        (u'1', u'Group1'),
        (u'2', u'Group2'),
        ...
       ]
   admin_group = models.CharField(_("Admin group"), max_length=1, choices = GROUP_CHOICES)

class model1(Parent):
    # ...


class model2(Parent):
    # ...
```

`model1` and `model2` now have `admin_group` field.